# curl / wget is adding an extra ^M when I append data to a file

Tags: linux, download, wget, curl, special-characters

Something is buzzing me about this. I'm trying to download two different hosts files into one, if I do this serperatly then everything is fine, but when I append the firs to the second a strange charachter `^M` appears at each line of the host file.

To give a real example here what I'm doing

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts -O /etc/hosts && curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHEF-KOCH/CKs-FilterList/master/HOSTS/CK's-Spotify-HOSTS-FilterList.txt" >> /etc/hosts
```

now `/etc/hosts` have these:
[image]

but when I do this separately, so

```
curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHEF-KOCH/CKs-FilterList/master/HOSTS/CK's-Spotify-HOSTS-FilterList.txt" > /tmp/hosts
```

now `/tmp/hosts` is perfectly normal

[image]

Why is this happening? Why when I download the files separately I don't get the wrong linefeed, yet when I combine them I get it. It's supposed to be 0x0a not 0x0a0x0d, why is this happening?

If you need to have a look at the files being downloaded you can head to the links in the commands:

1. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts
2. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHEF-KOCH/CKs-FilterList/master/HOSTS/CK%27s-Spotify-HOSTS-FilterList.txt

EDIT: I tried to append only the [second host](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHEF-KOCH/CKs-FilterList/master/HOSTS/CK%27s-Spotify-HOSTS-FilterList.txt) file to a dumb hosts file and the same happened, so we can omit that the first file is the cause of the problem

Comment: "It's supposed to be 0x0a not 0x0a0x0d" – I think what you get is `0x0d 0x0a`, not the other way around. Or is it really `0x0a 0x0d`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski whichever is `^M` on VIM.

Comment: Also be careful when processing headers from `curl -v`. They use CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No tool is adding anything. It's quite a confusion (but not your fault at all) because of few reasons.

There are two common line endings:

- Unix-style, one character denoted `LF` (or `\n` or `0x0a`),
- Windows-style, two characters, `CRLF` (or `\r\n` or `0x0d 0x0a`).

You download from two different URLs. It seems the server claims each file is `text/plain`, so [they should use `CRLF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519983). The second one (the one you `curl`) does indeed use `CRLF`, but the first one (the one you `wget`) illegally uses sole `LF` instead.

If you download only from the first URL (no matter if with `wget` or `curl`) and store the result in a `hosts1` file, then `file hosts1` will yield:

```
hosts1: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

(This means the line endings are `LF`, otherwise it would be `UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`).

If you download only from the second URL and store the result in a `hosts2` file, then `file hosts2` will yield:

```
hosts2: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

If you download both to the same file (say `hosts12`) in the way you do, you will get `LF` as line endings for lines that came from the first URL and `CRLF` as line endings for lines that came from the second URL.

In practice any tool that tries to tell whether a file uses `LF` or `CRLF` examines at most few initial lines, not all of them. Try `file hosts12` and you'll get:

```
hosts12: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

exactly as it was for `hosts1`. The same happens when you `vim hosts12`: the editor detects line endings as `LF` based on the beginning of the file. Then you skip to the end and you see many `^M`-s which denote `CR` characters. `vim` prints them because it doesn't consider `CR` to be a part of proper line ending in this case.

However when you `vim hosts2`, the editor correctly detects line endings as `CRLF`. The same `CR` characters that were printed as `^M` earlier, now are hidden from you because `vim` considers them to be parts of proper line endings. If you added a new line by hand, `vim` would use the Windows-style line ending even if you're on Unix. You may think the file is "perfectly normal" but it's not a normal Unix text file.

The confusion is because the two files on the server use different line endings; then `vim` tries to be smart.

In Linux (Unix in general) you want your `/etc/hosts` to use `LF` as line endings. See POSIX definitions of [line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) and [newline character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_243). It's explicitly stated the character is `\n`:

> 3.243 Newline Character (`<newline>`)
>   A character that in the output stream indicates that printing should start at the beginning of the next line. It is the character designated by `'\n'` in the C language.

I don't think tools are obligated to support `\r\n` then. The simple solution is to run `wget … && curl … >> …` exactly as you did, then invoke `dos2unix /etc/hosts`.

If I were you I would work with *another* file, say `/etc/hosts.tmp`. I would use `wget`, `curl`, `dos2unix`, `chmod --reference=/etc/hosts`, `chown --reference=/etc/hosts`. Only when the file is complete, I would `mv` it to replace `/etc/hosts`. This feature of [`rename(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) is relevant:

> If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access `newpath` will find it missing.

So any process would find either the old `/etc/hosts` (before `mv`) or the new one (after `mv`). Your current approach, directly working with `/etc/hosts` allows scenarios when another process finds the file incomplete or with wrong line endings near its end.

Comment: amazingly explained, thank you! Will it hurt if I keep things like they are? (will host file recognize `CRLF` as a proper line ending anyway?

Comment: @AK_ I think there's not such concept as "file that recognizes `CRLF` …", rather "tools that recognize `CRLF` …". In my Kubuntu at least *some* of them don't mind mixed line endings. I wouldn't count on it in general though. See POSIX definitions of [line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) and [newline character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_243). It's explicitly stated the character is `\n`. I don't think tools are obligated to support `\r\n` then.